# How to insert multiple images in the Django blog app?

Tags: django

What I want is similar to the stack overflow posts, I can add images in between the text, just simply copy the image and paste it in my blog while editing. is it possible?

I.ve seen some posts that can add a single image as post cover or add the designated number of images like 'must insert 3 images in a post'. that's not what I want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people offer the best answers they can, could you add links to the stack overflow posts you referred to? It appears there is a lot of context in those posts that you haven't included in the question. Perhaps even better, include the relevant context from those posts in your question with links to the posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you heard of the Django content management system (CMS) [Wagtail](https://wagtail.io/)? It really sounds like what you want is a CMS, and Wagtail is, as far as I know, the most popular and fleshed out one for Django. You can read in the Wagtail docs about [inserting images in a page](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.9.3/editor_manual/new_pages/inserting_images.html) (tailored for editors) or [using images in templates](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.9.3/topics/images.html) (tailored for developers).

Do keep in mind though that Wagtail is a whole CMS. If you were aiming for more limited functionality, that doesn't come with a bundle of other CMS niceties, you might want to look elsewhere.